# Joomla modules colliding Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, php, joomla

I have a test site I'm working on, basically a mockup of one site. And I installed two extensions. One is [RokSprocket](http://www.rockettheme.com/joomla/extensions/roksprocket), and the other is [Responsive contact form](http://joomladrive.com/index.php/extensions).

Now, when I disable my contact form module, roksprocket tabs work just fine. But when I enable it, they stop working.
I checked the console and I have this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getCoordinates'
    yjresponsive.js:72
    size_menu yjresponsive.js:72
    (anonymous function) yjresponsive.js:35
    (anonymous function) mootools-core.js:121
    (anonymous function) mootools-core.js:5
    Array.implement.each mootools-core.js:9
    invoke.fireEvent mootools-core.js:120
    j mootools-core.js:175
```

From inspecting the first error is in (72nd line of code)

```
function size_menu() {

    if ($('mmenu_holder')) {
        if (Browser.name == 'ie' && (Browser.version == 7 || Browser.version == 8)) {
            var size = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        } else {
            var size = window.getScrollSize().x;
        }

        var all_li = $$('ul.menunav li');

        if (all_li.length > 0) {
            var tops = all_li[0].getSiblings();
            var tops_count = tops.length + 1;
            var width = tops.getWidth().sum() + all_li[0].getWidth();
            var menu_width = $('topmenu_holder').getCoordinates().width;
        }

        if (size < 980) {
            $$('.top_menu,.top_menu_poz').removeClass('showmenu');
            $$('#mmenu_holder').setStyle('display', 'block');
        } else {
            $$('#mmenu_holder').setStyle('display', 'none');
            $$('.top_menu,.top_menu_poz').addClass('showmenu');
        }
        if (size > 980) {
            $$('#mmenu_holder').setStyle('display', 'none');
            $$('.top_menu,.top_menu_poz').removeClass('showmenu');
        }

    }
}
```

The one on 35 is

```
window.addEvent('domready', function () {
    showmenu();
    size_menu();
    if ($('logo')) {
        logo_size();
    }

});
```

The mootools one are just jumbeled up :\

So what is causing this error? My knowledge of JavaScript is nonexistent :S

I messaged the support for roksprocket, but they also pointed out at that error, nothing more...

I'm on Joomla 3.2.3. with [yougrids](http://joomlatemplates.youjoomla.info/yougrids/) template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Responsive Contact Form module introduces jQuery to your template. The module contains a file called 'mod_responsive_contact_form.php' which contains the following line:

`$document->addScript('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js');`

This causes a conflict with the variable `$` which is also used by MooTools. To get around this you will need to modify 'mod_responsive_contact_form.php'. I don't have any knowledge of Joomla or whatever so bear with me.

Immediately below the above line add the following so libraries other then jQuery can keep using `$`.

`$document->addScriptDeclaration('jQuery.noConflict();');`

After that you will need to modify the following line:

`$document->addScriptDeclaration('$(function () { $("input,select,textarea").not("[type=submit]").jqBootstrapValidation(); } );');`

to

`$document->addScriptDeclaration('jQuery(function () { jQuery("input,select,textarea").not("[type=submit]").jqBootstrapValidation(); } );');`

This should eliminate the errors you're experiencing.

Comment: This did it! Thank you! It's kinda weird since I added `JHtml::_('jquery.framework', false);` in index.php because I had a little scrollTop script in it, and I needed to remove the same conflict with $. But I guess this was specific to this module. Thanks again :)

I'll award the bounty in 22 hrs (SE says so...)

Comment: This is a very common problem with CMS and plugins/modules. Authors don't always take into account that other libraries might already be included. Glad it worked out :)

Comment: Yeah, I even mailed the authors, but got no answer. I'll send them this as a message, so that they can update it :D Thanks again :)